# C server socket accepts clients with no request

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I'll keep it simple.
Code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);
    if(error) printf("WinSock error!");
    SOCKET server;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(5657);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY); 
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET) printf("INVALID SOCKET!");
    error = bind(server, (LPSOCKADDR)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    if(error) printf("Connect Error!");
    listen(server, SOMAXCONN);
    printf("SERVER ESTABLISHED! LISTENING...\n");
    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    SOCKET client;
    client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, (int *)sizeof(client_addr));
    if(client==INVALID_SOCKET) printf("INVALID SOCKET!\n");
    printf("A CLIENT!");
    closesocket(server);
    WSACleanup();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But what I get is:

SERVER ESTABLISHED! LISTENING...
INVALID SOCKET!
A CLIENT!

I've done sockets in C# and I guess the server is supposed to listen and wait for a client, and whenever a client requests for a connection, the server should accept it, but the server accepts a socket without waiting, and this accepted socket is invalid, too! Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: What does `WSAGetLastError()` return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
(int *)sizeof(client_addr)
```

is wrong, you're casting the size to a pointer.

```
socklen_t client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);
```

Comment: Damn! Was typing this :) +1 for beating me

Comment: Hi. Thanks but I found out that socklen_t is undefined! Any alternative structs???

Comment: Looks like `int` should be fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (just replace `socklen_t` with `int`, _not_ `int *`).

Answer (score 1):

```
(int *)sizeof(client_addr)
```

You're casting the client_addr size into an int*, so you have a pointer that points to an address which is equal to the size of your client_addr.

You need to do:

```
socklen_t clntAddrLen = sizeof(client_addr);
client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &clntAddrLen);
```

This way is different because you have a variable of type socklen_t which holds the size of your client_addr. You're then getting a pointer (with &) that points to the memory address where that number is contained which is what you want.

Comment: Hi. Thanks but I found out that socklen_t is undefined! Any alternative structs??? I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: The socklen_t type is defined inside of WS2tcpip.h in windows. This is not transitively included from winsock2.h (AFAICT). You'll need to include WS2tcpip.h manually in order to use the socklen_t type. - taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4454036/857994

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that [accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will attempt to write to the last argument provided to it.

Change to:

```
int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_size);
```

Checking the value of [WSAGetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will provide the reason for failure.