# Get Local Port used by Socket

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I need to get the local port used by a (client) socket.

It was my understanding that `Windows Sockets performs an implicit bind function call`, therefore `getsockname()` after `sendto()` should provide the assigned port. However, it always sets 0 as the port number. Am I missing something?

ex:

```
if (sendto(sockfd, ...) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    printf("Sent\n");

if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, &sinlen) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    printf("port = %u\n", ntohs(sin.sin_port);
else
    printf("Error");

//result: Sent, port = 0
```

Comment: Does the sendto() function fail or does it work correctly?

Comment: @MartinRosenau Works correctly. Also confirmed the data sent (including header) is correctly formed via packet capture.

Comment: How is `sinlen` defined and initialised?

Comment: @alk `struct sockaddr_in sin;` `int sinlen = sizeof(sin);`

Comment: Is the code shown identical to the code producing a zero result?  Given you set `sinlen` as you indicate in comments, with the code shown, you should see a non-zero result.

Comment: I asked a ***[slightly different question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30603309/645128)***.  Although I got a non-zero result (below), I did not know why the value was not what I expected.  The answer I got may also be useful to you.

Comment: Had `sendto()` been told to send >0 bytes?

Comment: @ryyker Yes, identical. (It wasn't originally, but this unexpected behavior forced me to simplify it in search for an answer.)

Comment: @ryyker Your code there was connecting to the other machine on /its/ port 5000. My situation is somewhat similar in that I do not specify the port on the client-side, thus the system chooses it; I need to get the number the system chose after it does so.

Comment: @alk Yes, >0 bytes, and it does actually send the data.

Comment: Look at the link I embedded in my comment (5 up).  It will lead you to `getpeername()`, and explain that for ephemeral connections, that's how you get the port number.  In similar code I am actually working on right how, I do connect to a specific port number (provided by the server) but do not explicitly bind this information to the socket, I believe that results in an ephemeral connection

Comment: @ryyker You may have misunderstood; `getpeername` returns the (sock)address on the remote machine, `getsockname` returns the (sock)address on the local machine. I need the local port, NOT the remote port. Also, `The getpeername function can be used only on a connected socket. For datagram sockets, only the address of a peer specified in a previous connect call will be returned. Any address specified by a previous sendto call will not be returned by getpeername.` making it entirely useless in my case.

Comment: In that case, the original code in my answer worked perfectly for me to get ***local*** IP address and Port number.  And, because you stated in comments that you did indeed create and initialize `int len = sizeof(sin);` to use in `getsockname()`, the only other thing I can think of (although unlikely) is permissions/privileges.  If you are running on Windows 7 (or beyond) you might need to run elevated, i.e. _Run As Administrator_.  Have you checked to see if that effects your results?

Comment: ***[Here](http://www.binarytides.com/receive-full-data-with-recv-socket-function-in-c/)*** is a site with code I used to test the scenario you described by inserting the `getsockname()` function (and related code) starting on line 38.  It correctly returned my local IP address and port number.  Can you try it using this code?

Comment: @ryyker Yeah, I went so far as to copy-paste multiple tutorials (UDP without `connect()`, though, not TCP _with_ as yours) and none of them worked. Problem solved though, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

The only ambiguity I can see in your example code is what size you assigned to `sinlen` before calling. (you do not show it) If you are using ***[winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***, it should be defined, and assigned `int sinlen = sizeof(sin);`

I used this code on my system, and it returns a non-zero value for the port I am connecting through:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
int len = sizeof(sin);
if (getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len) == -1)
    //handle error
else
    printf("port number %d\n", ntohs(sin.sin_port));
```

By the way, The ***[ntohs function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** function returns the value in host byte order. If [ `sin.sin_port` ] is already in host byte order, then this function will reverse it. It is up to *[your]* application to determine if the byte order must be reversed.  *[text in brackets are my emphasis]*

***In answer to*** comment question ( ***[getsockname()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** ):

The function prototype for `getsockname()`:

```
int getsockname(
  _In_    SOCKET          s,
  _Out_   struct sockaddr *name,
  _Inout_ int             *namelen  //int, not socklen_t
);
```

For more discussion on ***[socklen_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3531474/645128)***

***Edit*** (address possible approach to re-setting sockets without rebooting PC.)
If winsock API calls cease to work predictably, you can re-start sockets without rebooting the PC by using ***[WSAStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** and ***[WSACleanup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***   (see code example at bottom of link for WSAStartup)

Comment: The values held by the `struct sockaddr_in` are expected to be in network-byte-order. If the machine uses network-byte-order as host-byte-order the host's implementations of the `ntoh*()` and `hton*()` functions are doing nothing.

Comment: Also the 3rd parameter to `getsockname()` ought to be of type `socklen_t`. This is important at least if `int` and `scoklen_t` are of different size, as the address is passed.

Comment: @alk - Thank you.  I tried to use socklen_t.  On my system, the `#include <winsock2.h>` does not have it defined.

Comment: Ah yes, this is windows. No issue here. Sry!

Comment: However, your "btw"'s 2nd half is nonsense, I'd say. Or did I somehow missunderstood you?

Comment: @alk - The comment I put at the bottom of my post (regarding your first and last comment) is quoted right from MSDN (with some emphasis added).  Is your comment regarding POSIX versions?

Comment: `sinlen` is defined as in your example. I copy-pasted your code, and it also prints 0 as the port number with no errors. I'll have to create a new project to see if something is interfering.

Comment: @user3140816 - Sorry not sure what could be the problem.  It would be good if you would post the solution once you find it.  Thanks.

Comment: MSDN writes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "*If the `netshort` parameter is already in host byte order ...*" (where `netsort` is the parameter `ntohs()`). This is correct (for windows) but **clearly different** from what you write.

Comment: @alk - okay, I made an edit in my answer to clarify the part that is my emphasis (for context with OP) of what netshort parameter is. In this context, it is sin.sin_port. I failed to edit that when I changed s_in to sin in the rest of the post earlier. Not sure why the down vote though.   ...  And by the way, `_In_ u_short netshort` is the parameter ***to*** `ntohs()`.  I understood that.

Comment: The OP is asking how to determine the LOCAL port number assigned automagically by the kernel for his `sendto()`, not the port number of the remote machine. None of this addresses his question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with a restart of the computer. Still unknown as to the actual cause, but at this point I'm just happy it's working.

If anyone has an idea for fixing the issue *without* a restart (for future readers), feel free to post.

Comment: Regarding _without_ a restart.  I may simply be a matter of calling WSAStartup, and WSACleanup.  See edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to know the LOCAL port, but your line

> `sendto(sockfd, ...)`

implies sockfd is the REMOTE descriptor.  Your later code may therefore give you info about the REMOTE port, not the LOCAL one.  'sockets' are not both ends, meaning one connection.  A socket is one end, meaning the IP and port number of one end of the connection.  The first parameter of your getsockname() is not a reference or a pointer, it is therefore not an output from the function, but an input.  You're telling the function to use the same socket descriptor that you just sent to, ie. the remote one.

Formatting error.  ntohs() returns unsigned short so the format should be %hu, not %u or %d.  If you grab too many bytes they are not the port.

Answer.  After using sendto() try using gethostname() then getaddrinfo() on the name that comes back.  Note: the addrinfo structures you get back will give you struct sockaddr pointers which you will need to re-cast to struct sockaddr_in pointers to access the local port number.

Comment: What is a "REMOTE descriptor"?

Comment: @Andrew - By "remote descriptor" I mean a file descriptor that refers to a remote socket.

Comment: Sorry @user3140816 (questioner), I now think my answer is wrong.  I think getaddrinfo() is useless for finding out port numbers RECENTLY USED.  The second param (service) being 0 does not act as a hint to allow any port number used in the output list, it is just copied into the output list (after being translated from service name to port number).  I might add, the design of this function is very bad; the second half of all the members of the addrinfo structure are useless in the 'hints' parameter, and the first half of all the members of the addrinfo structure are useless in the results.

Answer (score 0):

To find the local port number the kernel dreamed up when you issued a sendto() function perhaps you could write a routine to parse the output from the (gnu linux) commands 'ss' or 'netstat'.  (Not sure if these are POSIX compatible.)  Or maybe you could access /proc/net if you have the privilege.