# How to get local port not knowing socket

Tags: c++, sockets

My program works as client some outside service. I want to get local port using by my program. It wasn't problem when I had handle to socket, then probably I will use this way:

[Get Local Port used by Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597111/get-local-port-used-by-socket)

But **I don't get handle to socket** because socket is created somewhere in shared library provided by some company (I not have source only *.so). I have only function to create connection with some service with **random port**, and function to use this service, nothing more. 
So when I created connection I don't know what port choose system, but I would to know that after in my program.

```
#include "somesharedlibrary.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // some uid , 0 means choose random port (must be), user, password
    int i = CreateConnectionToSecretService("38324f42" , 0  , "admin" , "admin");
    if (i != 0){
        printf("Ok I have connection from service");
        // Now I have connection let's say on 0.0.0.0.:1234
        // I know that using netstat- antl, but of course
        // I don't know that in code. Therefore my question for You.
        // It is posible get local port which was used by system in this place ?
    }else{
        printf("something is wrong by.. by..")
    }

        return 0;
}
```

**SOLVED**

As said **SergeyA** after long discussions :). When My Program was connected to service were created 2 new file descriptor: for UDP, and TCP connection. For TCP is descriptor nr 4. Then enought write below code:

```
struct sockaddr_in foo;
socklen_t len = sizeof foo;
int f = getsockname(4, (struct sockaddr *)&foo, &len );
printf( "%s", inet_ntoa( foo.sin_addr));
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your OS?  There's probably not a platform-independent way to do what you want, but it should be possible.

Comment: You can try to hook the socket() function to intercept the socket creation. See here: http://fishi.devtail.com/weblog/2015/01/25/intercepting-hooking-function-calls-shared-c-libraries/

Comment: You can use `lsof` to get open file information for a process if you're using *nix.

Comment: @Jason. Yes I know but Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention .so, I take it is some of the *Nix variant. And since it is *nix, it means it is Linux :)

It is rather easy to do this. Just take a snapshot of process file descriptors before calling create connection - for instance, by reading /proc//fd - and than after calling connection. The extra descriptor you see there would be a new socket opened (if there is more than one, it means, library opened more than one descriptor - you will have to guess which is the one you need.) Now you have your descriptor and you can inquiry it.

Comment: Hmmm. Could You submit any example :) ? This is look not so easy :) After run my program. I get PID then was be created direcytory `/proc/PID/fd#` I see in this direcytory two position  `socket:[5840486]` and `socket:[5847359]` this number is it ? I also get in /proc/PID/fdinfo  four files 0 ,1 ,2 ,3, 4. if I open one of then I get : `pos: 0
flags: 0100002
mnt_id: 17`

Comment: File name you have there is your socket descriptor. You can use it in the call to getsockname.

Comment: Could You look form my post on  **EDIT 1**. I have tryed get some info form `getsocketname()` but I have error

Comment: What are you doing? Why are you treating something which was returned to you as a result of a fopen() as a socket? Of course it is not!

Comment: Ok. I see some diffrent, before Create connection doesn't have descriptor 4 and 5. They looks on using for shared library to connect with service, but I can't read this file `lrwx------ 1 mypc mypc 64 lis 17 17:46 4 -> socket:[5958532]` and `lrwx------ 1 mypcl mypc 64 lis 17 17:46 4 -> socket:[5958543]` **SergeyA** I understand Your idea but I don't know how do that, for what  pay attention, and when will use appropriate function. Please Help me more.

Comment: You do not need to read those files at all! All you need is their names. Their names give you the socket file descriptor. I am not sure what is confusing here.

Comment: How can call  these files created after connection to service? `5958532` and `5958543` ? or `1,2,3,4,5` in `/proc/FD/fd` or some new directory created after connect as `/proc/fd` ? I don't see nothing else what could be name this.

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in fd. Sorry for saying this, but your level of experise suggests you need to do some studying before taking on this task.

Comment: You Have complety right. I will must studying this, but now I need quickly solution. I have tryed open file 0, 1, 2, and works but I get diffrent number port as after command `lsof -Pi` and also don't get My local IP after `inet_ntoa( foo.sin_addr )`  but server IP probably which my program is connected.  Unlles I bad convert this data ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand a single sentence in the last question.

Comment: alffer executing command `lsof -Pi` i get result `service 18654 mypc    4u  IPv4 6230681      0t0  TCP *:47168 (LISTEN)` As You see port is **47168**  but in my program, after read `proc/FD/fd/2` in function `getsocketname()` Get me **36351** I using to convert function `ntohs(foo.sin_port)` . And result function `inet_ntoa( foo.sin_addr )` give result some external server IP no my local 0.0.0.0

Comment: Again, why are you doing anything with fd 2 if your socket fd, as reported, by lsof, is 4???

Comment: Because file 4 is only symbolic link and I can't open him. Look for Main Post **EDIT 2** what I tryed, and what is result

Comment: Sorry, can't help you anymore. I already exhausted all my resources.

Comment: Ok I understand. +1 from me for time and help. May be someone else try explain mi this little more. Thanx for all.