# Which function tells me what address the kernel bound the local socket to?

Tags: c, linux, function, sockets, ip-address

As a client I do a `socket()`, it gives me a number I store in `sktnum`.  I then do a `connect()` with `sktnum` and the remote address.  Hey presto, it succeeds, and I am told the kernel has selected a local IP address and port number (so as the server will know where to send back to).  What function (linux C/C++) do I call to find out what port and IP address the kernel selected.  (And please don't be one of those people who say "why do you want to know")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597111/get-local-port-used-by-socket

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. I understood it the following way:

> Computer "A" uses `socket()` and `connect()` to establish a TCP connection to computer "B" which is using `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()` and `access()`.
>
> The IP address and the TCP port on computer "B" is well known (of course - you connect to a **certain** TCP port on a **certain** computer).
>
> But how is it possible to find out the IP address and the TCP port on computer "A" belonging to this connection?

The function which will do that on computer "A" is `getsockname()`.

On computer "B" `getpeername()` will return that information.

If computer "B" has multiple IP addresses (e.g. multiple network cards) computer "B" may also use `getsockname()` to get its own IP address.

Before calling `connect()` the socket has no port number and no IP address, yet. So calling `getsockname()` before calling `connect()` makes no sense.

The reason for this is simple: If a computer has multiple network cards with different IP addresses the IP address on computer "A" side cannot be known before it is known which of the network cards must be used. (Note that `localhost` is seen as separate "network card" with the IP address 127.0.0.1 by the OS!)

**EDIT**

> But I think you might only get ... 192.168. ... It doesn't give you the ... IP address you are alloted on the internet.
> Your problem can be explained the following way:

The original idea of the internet was that every computer has its own global IP address (this is what you call: "addresses you are allocated on the internet").

There was never a change in this idea: Nearly any PC software (including the OS) is written for computers having a global IP address.

Because your provider can only give you one IP address your router is "fooling" your computers by "simulating" an internet where the local computers have global addresses (e.g. in the range 192.168.).

Because of this "simulation" the computer can behave exactly like 192.168.x.y is its global IP address in the internet. The computer does not even have any information about the fact that this is not a global IP address!

So it's clear that these functions return 192.168.x.y because the operating system "thinks" that this is the global address on the internet!

The only device that has information about the real global address (and about the real TCP port!!!) is the router!

Many providers use CGNAT which means that even multiple internet connections share one IP address. In this case the only device having that information is the provider's router.

If you need the real IP address and the real TCP port (as seen from the internet) you'll get that information from the router. Depending on the router model it will not be possible to get the information about the real addres.

I doubt that there is any router on the market which allows you to read out the real TCP port.

This was one reason why IPv6 was developed: With IPv6 any computer can have its own IP address again...

Comment: Martin - I don't think you're correct.  getsockname() requires the caller to supply a socket file descriptor (sockfd).  But we wouldn't know the local one.  We know the one we created with socket(), but when we used it with connect() it became associated with the REMOTE IP address, not the local one.

Comment: I think I may have worked out one answer, but it's still insufficient for what I want.  You could use gethostname() then getaddrinfo() on what it returns.  But I think you might only get 127.0.0.1 or an address beginning 192.168. etc which is what the gateway (router) may have alloted you in a DHCP operation.  It doesn't give you the (temporary) IP address you are alloted on the internet.

Comment: @Clive Please see my edit: Sorry, but I think what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your added message.  Yeah I guess you're right.  The info is not easily accessible (other than writing a specific program to access another server on the internet and ask it what IP it thinks I am.)  But then, that might only give the IP of the router?  Or the IP that the router injected into the packets as a way of knowing which of its computers should receive the response?  (Is that NAT?)  Or the IP of the ISP, or the IP the ISP allocated to my router?  Seems like it's a minefield of aliases.